# Subtract & get difference of two images(touchpaint) and get an integer value in Android

Tags: android

I have a requirement where the user needs to draw something on a FingerPaint like application and submits. I need to check to what extent the image matches and take the difference of the user's image with the ACTUAL image. The difference should then return an integer value. Depending on that, the user gets a score. Any suggestions is it possible to take difference of two images just like in MATLAB in Android?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/spatialite-android/downloads/list goto link. Download apk and decompile the apk and extract all the sources and other resources and native lib... it will help u..

Answer (score 0):

At first find out the coordinates of your 1st ans 2nd image and then insert it into SpatiaLite database, it has all functionality such as union, intersection, subtraction, covexhull etc between two or more objects.

[Take a look](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5186/sqlite-to-spatialite)

Or search about SpatiaLite.
It will help you what you want...
Have fun...

Answer (score 0):

i think you first get the ACTUAL image rect ,and record every pixel and its location. then you can get the same rect of the user pic,and compare all pixel. or use rect.contain() to found   if all pixel is in the rect.if all in the rece you should compare pixel location